# How to sum specific values within dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following nested dictionary and need to figure out how to sum all 'qty'.

```
data1 = {
    'Batch1': {
        'Pink': {'qty': 25, 'ordered': 15},
        'Blue': {'qty': 18, 'ordered': 20}
    },
    'Batch2': {
        'Coke': {'qty': 50, 'ordered': 100},
        'Sprite': {'qty': 30, 'ordered': 25}
    }
}
```

So the outcomes would be 123.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sum`:

```
data1 = {'Batch1': {'Pink': {'qty': 25, 'ordered':15}, 'Blue': {'qty':18, 'ordered':20}}, 'Batch2': {'Coke': {'qty': 50, 'ordered': 100},'Sprite': {'qty':30, 'ordered':25}}}
result = sum(b['qty'] for c in data1.values() for b in c.values())
```

Output:

```
123
```

Comment: I imported another python file that had that data1 dictionary within and tried that code, but got the typeerror: int obj not callable. is there something different you have to do when using an imported file?below is my code                                           
import filedata
dict1 = filedata.data1

result = sum(b['pop'] for c in dict1.values() for b in c.values())
print(result)

Comment: @owl1863 Please post your `dict1` structure contained in `filedata.py`.

Comment: It is the data/structure shown in the initial question. The only data within the imported file is the data1 dictionary, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Your `data1` was formatted funny, so here's what I used:

```
{'Batch1': {'Blue': {'ordered': 20, 'qty': 18},
  'Pink': {'ordered': 15, 'qty': 25}},
 'Batch2': {'Coke': {'ordered': 100, 'qty': 50},
  'Sprite': {'ordered': 25, 'qty': 30}}}
```

If you're not sure how deeply nested your dict will be, you can write a function to recursively traverse the nested dict looking for the `qty` key and sum the values:

```
def find_key_vals(query_key, base_dict):
    values = []
    for k, v in base_dict.items():
        if k == query_key:
            values.append(v)
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            values += find_key_vals(query_key, v)
    return values

find_key_vals('qty', data1)
# => [50, 30, 25, 18]

sum(find_key_vals('qty', data1))
# => 123
```